# C# `Int32` how to limit range correctly?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on my optimized `XorShift32` pseudo-random number generator to be used for unit tests. It's significantly faster than System.Random, with `unsafe` optimizations it's way faster. Plus I added server handy methods to make my unit testing easier. However I have a problem with it correctness since the overflow when using ranges close to `Int32.MinValue` and `Int32.MaxValue`.

Here's the method (I know it's incorrect):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a random integer that is within a specified range.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="min">The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.</param>
    /// <param name="max">The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.</param>
    /// <returns>A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.</returns>
    public int Next(int min, int max) {
        if (min == max) return min;
        Seed ^= Seed << 13;
        Seed ^= Seed >> 17;
        Seed ^= Seed << 5;
        if (min == int.MinValue && max == int.MaxValue) return unchecked((int)Seed);
        return min + (int)(Seed / Max * (max - min));
    }
```

When `Math.Abs(max - min) < Int32.MaxValue` it returns correct numbers, but otherwise the numbers overflow. First, the condition stated above seems to make sense for a human, but not necessarily  for the compiler or IL. Anything except `Int32.MaxValue` is less than `Int32.MaxValue` so using that in code is pointless. Then again I could cast max and min to `Int64`, then make the calculations, but the issue is it would defeat all optimizations gain here.

Any ideas how to limit the output range FAST?

Let's consider the test case: `var x = R.Next(-1, Int32.MaxValue)`. This code will fail miserably on this. How to make it correct without hitting the performance too much?

BTW, I know there's no practical reason of making such PRNG, I'm doing it solely for learning purpose.

Comment: What is `Max`? (Used in last line, doesn't appear to be defined anywhere)

Comment: Profiling is the key. My guess would be to just let the `OverflowException` be caught - that would mean you only need the special handling when there's actually a problem. The cost of the `try` itself should be negligible even in this case for the usual scenario.

Comment: Have you considered just using `unchecked`, "overflow" means you tried to do something that would overflow/wrap around, if that is OK (you want it to wrap around) you can simply use `unchecked`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and all: I'm terribly sorry I forgot to state `const double Max = uint.MaxValue;` - it's just max int cast to double for speeding up the calculations.

Comment: Change everything to double.

Comment: The wrapping around is what's happening. It causes the results to be incorrect, in test case for `(-1, Int32.MaxValue)` it gives values less than -1. BTW, as I noted in previous comment, `Max` is `double` so this is not an integer division, finding that it wouldn't make any sense is totally correct. Maybe the algorithm here is not as obvious as I thought - I first get the `double` value in range 0 to 1.0, then I multiply it by maximum integer. Oh wait... This is so wrong...

Comment: @Luaan It's very interesting point you made. I tested that adding the try / catch block didn't cause measurable performance hit, yet anyway I heavily use the special cases here for unit testing. I use the code to test various binary decoders if they interpret the data correctly on any given bit combinations, yet I of course want to save time not to go through  every possible number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at what Microsoft did for [`Random.Next(min, max)`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L160)

```
long range = (long)max-min;
```

They used `long` :-)

and then

```
return min + (int)(Seed / Max * range);
```

Comment: At almost exactly the same moment I used double there ;) I need to benchmark which is faster here... Well, I should checked the .NET source myself, I forgot it's open. Anyway, it was a nice learning experience. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually faster with double.